# Checking keywords from sentence input and then checking text file in Python

Tags: python

I've been learning Python and I've ran into some difficulty. I want to make a program where the user can input a sentence. The program then splits the sentence up and checks the words against a list. If any word is found in the list, it then finds that word in a text file and prints the line of the text file for which the word is located.

So far I have this:

```
    def getTakeaway():
    list = ["pizza", "italian", "chinese", "indian"]
    query = input("Please say what take away you'd like").lower()
    if set(list).intersection(query.split()):
        with open('takeaway.txt') as f:
            for line in open('takeaway.txt'):
                if query in line:
                    print (line)
                    break
    else:
        print("sorry not found")
getTakeaway()
```

It works for single word inputs such as 'pizza', however I get nothing back when searching for an input such as 'I would like pizza'.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've changed the code to this based on the advice given:

```
def getTakeaway():
    list = ["pizza", "italian", "chinese", "indian"]
    query = input("Please say what take away you'd like").lower()
    query_words = set(list).intersection(query.split())
    if query_words:
        with open('takeaway.txt') as f:
            for line in open('takeaway.txt'):
                if query_words in line:
                    print (line)
                    break
    else:
        print("sorry not found")
getTakeaway()
```

and I get this error:
if query_words in line:
TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not set

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
if query_words in line:
```

you are using a set which contains set(['i', 'would', 'like', 'some', 'pizza']). The expression "query in line" would now look for the set from the line. You need to iterate through the values in the set, a lot like you are iterating through the lines in the file:

```
for word in query_words:
    if word in line:
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This has sorted it!

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to search the lines for words in the intersection of the input and the hotlist, you need to actually do that

```
query_words = set(list).intersection(query.split())
if query_words:
     ...
```

Comment: amended my code to: 
`def getTakeaway():
    list = ["pizza", "italian", "chinese", "indian"]
    query = input("Please say what take away you'd like").lower()
    query_words = set(list).intersection(query.split())
    if query_words:
        with open('takeaway.txt') as f:
            for line in open('takeaway.txt'):
                if query_words in line:
                    print (line)
                    break
    else:
        print("sorry not found")
getTakeaway()`

and I get this error:
if query_words in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not set

Comment: Just edit the original question, that's illegible here